# How to access an element of a generic type in C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I'm working on a reusable database repository method for attaching and saving entities to a database using EntityFramework 4.3.

```
    private void SaveObject<T>(T entityToSave, DbSet<T> dbSet) where T : class
    {
        if (db.Entry(entityToSave).State == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            if (entityToSave.Id == Guid.Empty) // how do I access the Id property?
                dbSet.Add(entityToSave);
            else
                db.Entry(entityToSave).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
    }
```

The problem that I'm running into is that I need to tell my method which property is the Id so I can check to see if it is set or not. If it is empty, then I know I am creating a brand new record. Otherwise I am modifying an existing record.

How do I tell my method what the Id property is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an interface or base class that defines the `Id` property, and use that as your generic constraint. Example:

```
public interface IEntity
{
    Guid Id { get; }
}

private void SaveObject<T>(T entityToSave, DbSet<T> dbSet) where T : class, IEntity
    {
        if (db.Entry(entityToSave).State == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            if (entityToSave.Id == Guid.Empty) // how do I access the Id property?
                dbSet.Add(entityToSave);
            else
                db.Entry(entityToSave).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to create an interface containing the `Id` property.

Make all of your entity classes implement this interface and constrain `T` to implement it. (`where T : IHasId`)
You will then be able to access all of the members of this interface in your method.

Answer (score 1):

As others have shown, you can solve the problem by using an interface. Another possibility is to define an accessor delegate

```
private void SaveObject<T>(T entityToSave, DbSet<T> dbSet, Func<T,Guid> accessId)
{
    ...
    Guid id = accessId(entityToSave);
    ...
}
```

call with

```
SaveObject(entityToSave, dbSet, e => e.Id)
SaveObject(otherEntityToSave, dbSet, e => e.UserID)
```

The advantage over an interface, is that the ids can have different names and, together with a second generic parameter, even different types

```
private void SaveObject<T,I>(T entityToSave, DbSet<T> dbSet, Func<T,I> accessId)
{
    ...
    I id = accessId(entityToSave);
    ...
}
```